# How to correctly render meshes in separate opengl array objects?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am trying to render two triangles using separate Vertex Array objects. I am using OpenTK on C# (it provides almost the same API compared to defined OpenGL API). Here is my code:

I start from declaring my variables.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool loaded = false; //do not use glcontrol before it is not loaded
    private uint VAO1; 
    private uint object1_vertex_buffer; private uint object1_vertices_size; private uint object1_index_buffer;
    private uint object2_vertex_buffer; private uint object2_vertices_size; private uint object2_index_buffer;
    private uint VAO2;
    private uint VBO;
    int VertexShader;
    int FragmentShader;
    int ShaderProgram;
    private float[] object1_vertices = new float[] {
       -0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
        0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
        0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f
    };
    private float[] object2_vertices = new float[] {
        -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f
    };
    private int[] object1_indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
    private int[] object2_indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

I do painting of every frame here:

```
    private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded)//<--------------------------------------
            return;//<--------------------------------------
        // Clear the color buffer.
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.UseProgram(ShaderProgram);
        // Object 1
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);
        // drawelements requires count of elements, not bytes
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, object1_indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        // Object 2
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, object2_indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

       ErrorCode miauw = GL.GetError(); /// AND I GET HERE NO ERROR!
        /// at the end I have a screen filled by a background color, which is set in GL.ClearColor()
        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Here I do initialization of OpenGL arrays and buffers. I init here two Vertex Array Objects ( one for each triangle ), and two Buffers (for each) : vertices and indices. I set the proper length in bytes for them

```
    private void glControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        loaded = true;
        GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less);

        // Load the source of the vertex shader and compile it.
        VertexShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(VertexShader, MyOpenglThings.VertexShaderSource);
        GL.CompileShader(VertexShader);

        // Load the source of the fragment shader and compile it.
        FragmentShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(FragmentShader, MyOpenglThings.FragmentShaderSource);
        GL.CompileShader(FragmentShader);

        // Create the shader program, attach the vertex and fragment shaders and link the program.
        ShaderProgram = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
        GL.AttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(ShaderProgram);


        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068792/drawing-multiple-objects-in-opengl-with-different-buffers
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072056/rendering-two-objects-with-opengl-and-vertex-array-objects
        GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO1);
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);
        GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO2);
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);

        // Object 1 vertex positions
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object1_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object1_vertices,BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
        // Object 1 vertex indices
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object1_index_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object1_index_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object1_indices.Length * sizeof(int), object1_indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
        // Object 2 vertex positions
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object2_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object2_vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
        // Object 2 vertex indices
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object2_index_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object2_index_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object2_indices.Length*sizeof(int), object2_indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

    }
```

I free the allocated opengl resources (it does not relate to my question, it is not even called by now heh)

```
    private void CleanupOpenGL() {
          // ...
    }

}
```

I have copied shader codes:

```
class MyOpenglThings
{

    // A simple vertex shader possible. Just passes through the position vector.
    public const string VertexShaderSource = @"
        #version 330
        layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
        void main(void)
        {
            gl_Position = position;
        }
    ";

    // A simple fragment shader. Just a constant red color.
    public const string FragmentShaderSource = @"
        #version 330
        out vec4 outputColor;
        void main(void)
        {
            outputColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    ";
}
```

But when I launch a program, I get only a window filled with SkyBlue Color. At least, opengl is capable of rendering background color. But I want to get two red triangles too.

What's wrong in there? How do I get rendering two meshes in Vertex Array Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an array of generic vertex attribute data ([`GL.VertexAttribPointer`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.GL.html#OpenTK_Graphics_ES30_GL_VertexAttribPointer_System_Int32_System_Int32_OpenTK_Graphics_ES30_All_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_IntPtr_)), the [Vertex array object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) which should store the definition has to be bound.
This is the case for the specification of `VAO2`, but not for `VAO1`, because after

> ```
> GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO1);
> GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);
> GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO2);
> GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
> ```

the vertex array object `VAO2` is bound.

Furthermore, the generic vertex attribute array has to be enabled by [`GL.EnableVertexAttribArray`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Graphics.ES30.GL.html#OpenTK_Graphics_ES30_GL_EnableVertexAttribArray_System_Int32_). The state if a vertex array is enabled or disabled is stored in the vertex array object, too:

```cs
GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO1);
GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);

// Object 1 vertex positions
GL.GenBuffers(1, out object1_vertex_buffer);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertex_buffer);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object1_vertices,BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// [...]

GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO2);
GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);

// Object 2 vertex positions
GL.GenBuffers(1, out object2_vertex_buffer);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertex_buffer);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object2_vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above really helped. (I am posting here, because comment does not fit code well.)
 So, my load code now looks like:

```
        private void glControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        loaded = true;
        GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less);

        // Load the source of the vertex shader and compile it.
            // ....
        // Load the source of the fragment shader and compile it.
            // ....
        // Create the shader program, attach the vertex and fragment shaders and link the program.
            // ....
        GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO1);
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO1);

        // Object 1 vertex positions
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object1_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object1_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object1_vertices,BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // Object 1 vertex indices
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object1_index_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object1_index_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object1_indices.Length * sizeof(int), object1_indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.GenVertexArrays(1, out VAO2);
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO2);
        // Object 2 vertex positions
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object2_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertex_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, object2_vertices.Length * sizeof(float), object2_vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // Object 2 vertex indices
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out object2_index_buffer);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object2_index_buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, object2_indices.Length*sizeof(int), object2_indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

    }
```

parameter of GL.EnableVertexAttribArray should match the value in shader program.

Also changed a bit geometry coordinates, because triangles used to overlap.